# Convert an interface to a tuple in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to convert an interface into a tuple of keys and values. I was wondering if this would be possible using generics, but don't know enough about the language features to do this.

This is the kind of thing I would like to do:

```
interface Person {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

type Args = ToTuple<Person> // result would be ['name', string, 'age', number]

function DoSomethingWithArgs(...args: Args) {
    return (
        args[0] === 'name' &&
        typeof args[1] === 'string' &&
        args[2] === 'name' &&
        typeof args[3] === 'number'
    )
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure why you want this, but here goes...

Using ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52933137) to convert a mapped type to an intersection of functions that we can then match against different type parameters, we can define `ToTuple` in a way that will work for a fixed maximum number of members of the original interface.

```
type IntersectionOfValues<T> =
  {[K in keyof T]: (p: T[K]) => void} extends
    {[n: string]: (p: infer I) => void} ? I : never;

type IntersectionOfFunctionsToType<F, T> =
    F extends {
        (na: infer NA, a: infer A): void;
        (nb: infer NB, b: infer B): void;
        (nc: infer NC, c: infer C): void;
    } ? [NA, A, NB, B, NC, C] :
    F extends {
        (na: infer NA, a: infer A): void;
        (nb: infer NB, b: infer B): void;
    } ? [NA, A, NB, B] :
    F extends {
        (na: infer NA, a: infer A): void
    } ? [NA, A] :
    never;

type ToTuple<T> = IntersectionOfFunctionsToType<
    IntersectionOfValues<{ [K in keyof T]: (k: K, v: T[K]) => void }>, T>;

interface Person {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

type Args = ToTuple<Person> // ['name', string, 'age', number]
```

An alternative approach would be to use [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286) on `keyof` the interface, but I believe that going through a union may carry a greater risk of losing the order of the members of the interface.  (I believe I've seen unions lose order in the past, though I couldn't reproduce it in tests in the playground just now.)  In the solution above, it's well-established that intersections are ordered, so we are only relying on the mapped types to preserve order and the inference process in `IntersectionOfValues` to generate the contravariant candidates in order and intersect them in order.  This is still implementation-dependent behavior, but I think it's unlikely to change.