# Typescript String union to tuple

Tags: typescript

In Typescript is it possible to convert the union of keys from a mapped type to a tuple?

For example, using the following type as the input:

```
{
    a: string; 
    b: number;
};
```

Can I output the type:

```
['a', 'b'];
```

Comment: Do you mean `type Test =  Foo<{ a: any, b: any }> // => "a" | "b"`?

Comment: No, I'm specifically looking for a fixed-length tuple of the keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Comment: Sadly probably yes. I was hoping the changes allowing recursive conditional types in 4.1 could have opened the door for something

Comment: Note that `{a: number, b: number}` and `{b: number, a: number}` are the same type, so I'm not sure how you expect `["a", "b"]` as opposed to `["b", "a"]`to come of that.  Or would you be okay with `["a","b"] | ["b", "a"]`? If so there might be a different question that's a duplicate of

Comment: i.e., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194653/use-tuple-instead-of-array-of-union-within-type) (see `UnionToAllPossibleTuples`)

Comment: @jcalz  for my use case order is not important. I upvoted your linked answer. Thank you.