# Typescript: Get a tuple with the fixed length according to the number of enum members

Tags: typescript, types, enums, tuples

Let's say I have a enum

```js
enum Chest {
  ID,
  NAME,
  CAPACITY,
  OPEN_WIN_POINTS,
}
```

And I want to make a tuple with the same length as the number of the values in the enum. So for the example above I want the string tuple with the length of 4:

```js
type ChestStringTuple = EnumTuple<string, Chest>

const correctTuple: ChestStringTuple = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'goo']
const incorrectTuple1: ChestStringTuple = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']  // The number of tuple members differs from 4
const incorrectTuple2: ChestStringTuple = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', false]  // The tuple has non-string members
```

Is there any way to get the number of enum members and use it as the tuple length?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489261/typescript-can-i-define-an-n-length-tuple-type/52490977#52490977

Comment: @AlekseyL. that's a good one, thanks! If I only could get enum length somehow.

Comment: Don't think it's possible. Try to describe what's the real use case and maybe someone will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Combining solutions to *various* questions asked here on SO, I managed to create a solution that should be exactly what you're looking for!

First, [let's grab a type that can build us a tuple](https://medium.com/swlh/crazy-powerful-typescript-4-1-features-26036f4de6bc#c30b)!

```js
type BuildTuple<Current extends [...T[]], T, Count extends number> =
  Current["length"] extends Count
    ? Current
    : BuildTuple<[T, ...Current], T, Count>

type Tuple<T, Count extends number> = BuildTuple<[], T, Count>
```

[Then we'll hop on over to this SO question, which has some really useful union helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858763)!

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> =(U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never>;
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? A : never;
```

Then we're gonna *rewrite* the main method from that SO answer, since our goal isn't to convert a union to a tuple (which I do NOT recommend doing - [read this for an explanation as to why](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468375328))

```js
type UnionCount<U, L extends any[] = []> = {
  0: PopUnion<U> extends infer SELF ? UnionCount<Exclude<U, SELF>, [any, ...L]> : never;
  1: L['length'];
}[[U] extends [never] ? 1 : 0];
```

And from there, the rest is fairly straightforward. We'll make a couple of alias types, to make it easier to read

```js
type InterfaceLength<T> = UnionCount<keyof T>;
type EnumLength<T> = UnionCount<T>;
```

And if we *combine* all of that together, we can create our *final* enum

```js
type InterfaceTuple<T, L> = Tuple<T, InterfaceLength<L>>;
type EnumTuple<T, L> = Tuple<T, EnumLength<L>>;
```

Your code:

```js
enum Chest {
  ID,
  NAME,
  CAPACITY,
  OPEN_WIN_POINTS,
}

type ChestStringTuple = EnumTuple<string, Chest>

const correctTuple: ChestStringTuple = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'goo']    // Valid
const incorrectTuple1: ChestStringTuple = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']        // Not valid
const incorrectTuple2: ChestStringTuple = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', false] // Not valid
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx6a7w)

*Use at your own risk.*

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to get the number of elements in a union. . .