# A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeof

`Object.keys() as const` not working. How can I achieve this? (Suppose I don't know the content of the object, I don't know what keys does my object have)

```
const values = Object.keys(myObject) as const;
```

I need the `as const` to get string literal types

```
let name: typeof values[number];
```

Comment: why are you using `as ...` it should know what that is automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do

```
let name: keyof typeof myObject
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503813/get-dictionary-object-keys-as-tuple-in-typescript) question for why strongly typing `Object.keys` might be a bad idea.

Comment: this doesn't work if MyObject has type of an index signature. for example: type MyObject = {
  [key: string]: string;
};

const obj: MyObject = {
  name: 'John',
  age: "age",
};