# Create an array type containing all distinct keys of provided type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a generic type, say

```
type KeyArr<T>
```

that will contain the union of `T`'s key permutations

For example:

```
type foo = KeyArr<{a:1, b:2}>;
```

should be the same as

```
type foo = ['a', 'b'] | ['b', 'a'];
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: There's a reasonably clean solution that gives you a union of all permutations, i.e. `['a', 'b'] | ['b', 'a']` instead of just `['a', 'b']`, which kind of makes sense as properties are not ordered in types. If you're interested in this, I can write it up.

Comment: I would absolutely love it if it is not too much of a hassle

Comment: That is quite a late response! But it turns out I still had this lying around in my browser history: https://tsplay.dev/NVnDqN

Comment: This is just fantastic! Precisely what I was looking for. Please post an answer to this question so I could confirm it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing a union of all permutation tuples is actually a bit simpler than converting a union to a single tuple. A recursive mapped type with a conditional to return `[]` rather than `never` on empty objects, will do the job:

```
type KeyArr<T> =
  keyof T extends []
  ? []
  : {[K in keyof T]: [K, ...KeyArr<Omit<T,K>>]}[keyof T]

type Foo1 = KeyArr<{}>               // []
type Foo2 = KeyArr<{a:1, b:2}>       // ["a", "b"] | ["b", "a"]
type Foo3 = KeyArr<{a:1, b:2, c: 3}> // ["a", "b", "c"] | ["a", "c", "b"] | ["b", "a", "c"] | ["b", "c", "a"] | ["c", "a", "b"] | ["c", "b", "a"]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIEEBOSA8AVAfFAvAKCigGt4B7AMynSggA9gIA7AEwGcoBtAXQKgH5OPQgC4oAbw4woAS0bEyldF1GSANFAB0WuIhSoA8gFtpwDKpiZMXAL4cSIClR55QkKADFSpAIy5Y8ZDQxa2xCMPCIgHpIwRdwaE9SACY-HUDUMQBDYW91ACNhJJCIwmjOACJM8vVyvPKuKAAfCrqaqp5XBK8AZlSAvSyc-ML1AGNRbuKyjkrqqFq58tH6poqqmuWauobmmdb59fnlnZbFzYOV3aXFw4WTmfOFtvq8IA)

The union types will quickly get really big though. For an object with 8 properties, the union has 40320 members and TypeScript gets noticeably slow, and for 9 properties (which would create a union of 362880) it fails altogether.

Answer (score 1):

In general - yes, it's possible. If having an Array type that accepts every key from object is sufficient in your case, take a look at code below. If you need Tuple type it's more complex, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503813/get-dictionary-object-keys-as-tuple-in-typescript)

```
type KeyArr<T extends object> = Array<keyof T>
```

Comment: The link you provided is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
type KeyArr<T> = Array<keyof T>;
```

Note this type allows repetition of keys in the array.

Comment: I need it to contain every key exactly once. Is that possible?