# Convert list of properties to property tuple

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53503813/798371), but I think it lacks a lot of the main caveats and concerns raising issues there because I'm not making any assumptions that the properties of a given interface are a closed or ordered set.

Suppose I have an interface and couple of functions like this:

```js
interface Person {
    givenNames: string,
    familyNames: string,
    charactersToDisplayNames: number,
    age: number,
    weight: number,
    fastest5KTime: number,
    //... could be plenty of others
}
function writeFields<
    T extends object,
    F extends (keyof T)[]
>(
    dest : T, 
    fieldsToWrite : F,
    valuesToWrite : WhatTypeGoesHere<T, F>, //Can be defined above
) {/*...*/}
function setNames(dest: Person, givenNames: string, familyNames: string) {
    writeFields(
        dest, 
        ['givenNames', 'familyNames', 'charactersToDisplayNames'],
        //In this case, the 3rd param should be
        //a tuple of type [string, string, number]
        [givenNames, familyNames, givenNames.length + 1 + familyNames.length]
    )
}
//other functions set other fields, or do so with parameters, etc...
//the desire is to avoid any non-type refactoring esp. to writeFields().
```

How should the type noted above as `WhatTypeGoesHere` be defined so that the third parameter has proper type-checking?

Comment: You should be [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `F` to `(keyof T)[]` via `F extends (keyof T)[]` and not making it a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) via `F = (keyof T)[]`.  Please [edit] that since I don't think you're trying to ask about this, but it won't work the way you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the `valuesToWrite` property a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where you take every element type in the `fieldsToWrite` type (I'm changing this from `F` to `K`) and index into `T` with it.

Like this:

```
function writeFields<
  T extends object,
  K extends readonly (keyof T)[]
>(
  dest: T,
  fieldsToWrite: readonly [...K],
  valuesToWrite: { [I in keyof K]: T[K[I]] },
) {/*...*/ }
```

I'm giving `fieldsToWrite` a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) of the form `[...K]` instead of just `K` to give the compiler a hint that it should infer a tuple type and not an unordered array type from the `fieldsToWrite` argument.

Also, it's not super important whether or not the tuple types are mutable or [`readonly` tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) but `readonly` ones are less restrictive (e.g., `string[] is assignable to readonly string[]` but not vice versa) so I used `readonly`.

Let's test it out:

```
writeFields(
  dest,
  ['givenNames', 'familyNames', 'charactersToDisplayNames'],
  [givenNames, familyNames, givenNames.length + 1 + familyNames.length]
) // okay
// T is Person, K is ["givenNames", "familyNames", "charactersToDisplayNames"]

writeFields(
  dest,
  ['age', 'familyNames'],
  ['oops', 'okay'] // error!
  //~~~~~ <-- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
);
```

Looks good.  The compiler knows which values belong at which index when you call `writeFields()` and will complain if you pass in something bad.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-cgS9AoFgoABCeeJAB+z+fyH6AFp3+dhLoUCbldKJqYtMIBYGAdgYBgXggHAljxsgYBYAhP5-uY-hQCaST7AATAAzNh2EXLwRG1IkYGVFAfDMs0ODTOy4HkdAfDahgwo3guSHYG0mpyPkboMCorEjGACDggQiQVCgvLAJswEIUhcDkFgwA5HAIDFKBIDvkUv6AvATQ3pwIx6Ek8ltP83Szhg+wXKZQA)

Comment: Thanks much, this is quite helpful! However, it seems to fail on a [modest extension](https://tsplay.dev/NrnJ3N) (still simplified in terms of not having proper limits/error handling/etc.) in which type T is pulled from a map. Am I missing something fairly obvious, or is this solution brittle to extensions like that?