# How do I assign to a variable-specified key of a `Partial<MyInterface>` without an error that it can't be assigned to undefined?

Tags: typescript, undefined, assign, partial

In [this TypeScript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHsogAoBs4Ce0yA3qAM5hQCuAthOAHJz0BcyA5OXAB7oAOAC3QgIHZAB9OCfFFAQw4qRyp1+CjgG4AvgChQkWIhQBhYVAAmeQsTIhKNekxYR2HfsDgh0SzpgDmXr4cAG7AAEZQcEIiYjr64NDwSMgAQnDk5NZEUKQUqk5gzGycFujU4bgo4RnkwWAVcME1mcj+1MBgcFBaegZJxsgAIo7ZtgDWnQCSkLQm5eDsIHTh0PFgBOrIU-YFDF24wJTIALxomDj4OZLIZphWV8RS6ZljuVIjdG+aCYbJKAApOAAL2BAEVqN1IGBSLpkPDkOYQOwMFg3gAaOEIhDmCzkdh3SwYrHwlr4tK1YkI5AWRzkz60N66PQWCAybooGDUEAIMDAETIKBsmidAA8ACVkBAeJAQHjkOMIAR0DBkEDQRCoQoAHwACig6CqABV0OLhR0wAAxTDscUASmQ7HV4MhUGhAG1xQBdH4IETHVm0dCWkCnZBcnl8gW6knIAD0ccY6Eg7CmqoNVXIyA5gog6jgkAsiOgKE6XGQAHkANKaZCxhNgQQofDHIUIEUwmCYbO5-OFwWGlAAd2AuFwyFWyFAyEbKD9tHC6AAdLGMxByCadjJqKzHchdYrlarnZq3Qo7e6vZiHexsFDPLhRSfXdDtbDqVUYfPF3u726H0+IIulqYBvmcJDaD81JdlAuqfgOVTICqCHrpuPK4DuEAOiQsbUgmACiUAGrkYDkLqABMADM5HkXa7BGpsKAcKilw2O8ty4m8NwvFkjzsQybwcLhCIJkcyDeDCtTAP4IBwJUKBgOgM6MZw3KsjA8gWBwK7UtS37oO6a5emGbYdvqg52lBCJ6NSQoNFgyD6T8ehAA), also repeated below, there is a function which builds up a partial object in the application's type system from component parts.  However, it doesn't work with the noted error that all the result's properties are `undefined` in a way that prevents assigning anything else to them.

This is a simplified refactor of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73507606/798371) meant to avoid having the simplifying refactor invalidate any points of an answer posted there; you can see more of what was previously attempted in that description.

How do I get rid of this error while still dynamically building up an object?

---

The code at the [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHsogAoBs4Ce0yA3qAM5hQCuAthOAHJz0BcyA5OXAB7oAOAC3QgIHZAB9OCfFFAQw4qRyp1+CjgG4AvgChQkWIhQBhYVAAmeQsTIhKNekxYR2HfsDgh0SzpgDmXr4cAG7AAEZQcEIiYjr64NDwSMgAQnDk5NZEUKQUqk5gzGycFujU4bgo4RnkwWAVcME1mcj+1MBgcFBaegZJxsgAIo7ZtgDWnQCSkLQm5eDsIHTh0PFgBOrIU-YFDF24wJTIALxomDj4OZLIZphWV8RS6ZljuVIjdG+aCYbJKAApOAAL2BAEVqN1IGBSLpkPDkOYQOwMFg3gAaOEIhDmCzkdh3SwYrHwlr4tK1YkI5AWRzkz60N66PQWCAybooGDUEAIMDAETIKBsmidAA8ACVkBAeJAQHjkOMIAR0DBkEDQRCoQoAHwACig6CqABV0OLhR0wAAxTDscUASmQ7HV4MhUGhAG1xQBdH4IETHVm0dCWkCnZBcnl8gW6knIAD0ccY6Eg7CmqoNVXIyA5gog6jgkAsiOgKE6XGQAHkANKaZCxhNgQQofDHIUIEUwmCYbO5-OFwWGlAAd2AuFwyFWyFAyEbKD9tHC6AAdLGMxByCadjJqKzHchdYrlarnZq3Qo7e6vZiHexsFDPLhRSfXdDtbDqVUYfPF3u726H0+IIulqYBvmcJDaD81JdlAuqfgOVTICqCHrpuPK4DuEAOiQsbUgmACiUAGrkYDkLqABMADM5HkXa7BGpsKAcKilw2O8ty4m8NwvFkjzsQybwcLhCIJkcyDeDCtTAP4IBwJUKBgOgM6MZw3KsjA8gWBwK7UtS37oO6a5emGbYdvqg52lBCJ6NSQoNFgyD6T8ehAA) is:

```js
interface HornPlayer {instrumentName: 'saxophone' | 'clarinet' | 'trumpet';}
interface ChordPlayer {instrumentName: 'piano' | 'organ' | 'vibraphone';}
interface BassPlayer {instrumentName: 'double bass' | 'tuba' | 'bass guitar';}
interface DrumPlayer {kitItemCount: number;}
type Instrumentalist = HornPlayer | ChordPlayer | BassPlayer | DrumPlayer;
interface JazzQuartet {
    horn: HornPlayer,
    chords: ChordPlayer,
    bass: BassPlayer,
    drums: DrumPlayer
}
declare function recruit<R extends keyof JazzQuartet>(roleToRecruitFor: R) : JazzQuartet[R];
const demoFn = function (
    //Note: If roles are repeated here it's OK; 
    //the last recruit for a repeated role will be in the combo.
    rolesToInclude : (keyof JazzQuartet)[],
) : Partial<JazzQuartet> {
    let combo : Partial<JazzQuartet> = {};
    for(let role of rolesToInclude) {
        //Error ts(2322): Type 'HornPlayer | ChordPlayer | BassPlayer | DrumPlayer'
        //is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
        combo[role] = recruit(role);
    }
    return combo;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use `Partial` type, but rather something more sophisticated

Comment: Yes, exactly. Add the `Role extends keyof JazzQuartet` type parameter to de `demoFn` and use it to `Pick<JazzQuartet, Role>`

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Removing my comment above with your answer below that actually solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Pick<object, key>` type instead of `Partial<object>`. This would require having a type parameter for the key, a.k.a. the "role" in the jazz quartet:

```
interface JazzQuartet {
    horn: {
        instrumentName: 'saxophone' | 'clarinet' | 'trumpet'
    }
    chords: {
        instrumentName: 'piano' | 'organ' | 'vibraphone'
    },
    bass: {
        instrumentName: 'double bass' | 'tuba' | 'bass guitar'
    },
    drums: {
        kitItemCount: number
    }
}

declare function recruit<R extends keyof JazzQuartet>(roleToRecruitFor: R) : JazzQuartet[R];

function combine<Role extends keyof JazzQuartet>(roles: Role[]): Pick<JazzQuartet, Role> {
    const combo = {} as Pick<JazzQuartet, Role>

    for (const role of roles) {
        combo[role] = recruit(role)
    }

    return combo
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/mAQ2km)*.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty helpful. For those coming after, [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXj1om) is about the minimum difference from the original.