# TypeScript Narrowing Rest Arguments to Type

Tags: typescript, narrowing, type-narrowing

I am attempting to write a TypeScript wrapper around an existing JavaScript system that posts and sends events, for the sake of this question, the underlying JavaScript system cannot be changed.

The underlying event system is untyped, and essentially has `publish` and `subscribe` events, like so.

```
publish(eventName: string, ...args: any[])
subscribe(eventName: string, callback: Function)
```

Without typing, you would subscribe or publish to an event like so.

```
subscribe("myEvent", (myNumber: number, myString: string) => { 
    //... 
};

publish('myEvent', 1,  'hello');
```

I am attempting to write a type safe wrapper around this, which currently looks like so.

```
type MyEvent = {
    myNumber: number;
    myString: string;
};

type EventDefs = {
    "myEvent": MyEvent
};

type Event = keyof EventDefs;

function typedSubscribe<T extends Events>(
  eventName: T,
  callback: (payload: EventDefs[T]) => void
): void {
  subscribe(eventName, (...args: unknown[]) => {
    callback(args);
  });
}
```

However obviously at this point `unknown[]` or `any[]` cannot be infered to `EventDefs[T]` by the compiler.

On the point of `subscribe` it is safe to assume the arguments are correct.

How do I narrow the `unknown[]` type of `...args` to `EventDefs[T]`? For example, when subscribing to `myEvent`, the event type would be `MyEvent`.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjpY1m) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer (it might be the same as the picture of code in the answer below; it's hard to be sure because I can't run pictures in my IDE.  In any case pictures of code are not  acceptable answers for SO, so until they fix it I'm not sure we can do much about it).  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky part is to convert record type to tuple of its fields' types. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503813/get-dictionary-object-keys-as-tuple-in-typescript#answer-55858763), slightly modified. Note that in some cases this transformation is ambiguous and faulty (see mentioned question).

```
type SomeEvent = {
  n1: number;
  b1?: boolean;
};

type EventDefs = {
  'someEvent': SomeEvent;
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends never ? never : (arg: U) => never) extends (arg: infer I) => void ? I : never;
type UnionToMappedTuple<R, T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends never ? never : (t: T) => T> extends (_: never) => infer W ? [...UnionToMappedTuple<R, Exclude<T, W>>, W extends keyof R ? R[W] : never] : [];
type RecordToTuple<R> = UnionToMappedTuple<R, keyof R>;

type EventTuples = {
  [K in keyof EventDefs]: RecordToTuple<EventDefs[K]>;
}

declare function typedPublish<T extends keyof EventTuples>(type: T, ...args: EventTuples[T]): void;
declare function typedSubscribe<T extends keyof EventTuples>(type: T, callback: (...args: EventTuples[T]) => void): void;

/* Examples */
typedPublish('someEvent', 1, true);
typedPublish('someEvent', 1);            // (!) Expected 3 arguments, but got 2
typedPublish('someEvent', 1, true, 'b'); // Expected 3 arguments, but got 4
typedPublish('someEvent', true, 1);      // Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
typedPublish('someEvent', 1, 2);         // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

typedSubscribe('someEvent', (n1: number, b1?: boolean) => {});         // ok
typedSubscribe('someEvent', (n1: number, b1: boolean) => {});          // Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
typedSubscribe('someEvent', (n1: number, b1: boolean, x3: any) => {}); // Argument of type '(n1: number, s1: boolean, x3: any) => void'
    // is not assignable to parameter of type '(args_0: number, args_1: boolean | undefined) => void'.
typedSubscribe('someEvent', (n1: number, n2: number) => {});           // Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'
typedSubscribe('someEvent', (s1: string) => {});                       // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
typedSubscribe('someEvent', (n1: number) => {});                       // ok
```

Unfortunately, there are still problems with optional properties/parameters.