# Narrowing of string - count of values

Tags: typescript

If I have a type

```
type SomeType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

is there any typescript function that will return count of different values a variable of type SomeType can have:

```
assertEq(someFn(SomeType), 3)
```

Comment: If you have a union type and you want to create a tuple representation which should depend on the union you can take a look on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676439/create-constant-array-type-from-an-object-type/69676731#69676731

Comment: Thanks for a tip. In this case I had to have something that works like an enum so the Cerbrus's approach is a perfect match for my "problem"

Comment: you don't need an enum. `TupleUnion<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>` --> `['a','b','c'] | ['b','a','c'] | ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript types only exist in your IDE / compiler. They're not actually there, when you run your code.

This means that you can't access the type / iterate over it.

An alternative could be to use a `const array`, and extract an type from that:

```
const Types = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type SomeType = typeof Types[number];
```

Then you can just use `Types.length` in your test.