# Declaration of an array with unique values

Tags: typescript

I need some like this if it's possible

```js
export enum Roles {
  Role1 = 'Role1',
  Role2 = 'Role2',
}

export interface SomeInterface {
  permissions: Set<Roles>;
}

const someInterface: SomeInterface = {
  // values must be unique, if there are duplicates, typescript should warn about it
  permissions: [Roles.Role1, Roles.Role2],
}
```

[image]

I would be glad to get any tips, because I could not solve this typing problem myself

Comment: A `Set<T>` is a class that you need to instantiate and you cannot just assign an array to a property that is one.

Comment: Do you want a set or an array?  How many entries will your enum have?  If it's more than about 8 you can't represent "all possible exhaustive arrays without duplicates" as a specific type and you'd instead have to use a generic type instead, so `SomeInterface` would become `SomeInterface<T extends Roles[]>`.  I think we need more info here to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this type:

```js
export enum Roles {
  Role1 = 'Role1',
  Role2 = 'Role2',
}
// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];


export interface SomeInterface {
  permissions: TupleUnion<keyof typeof Roles>;
}

const someInterface: SomeInterface = {
  permissions: [Roles.Role1, Roles.Role2] // ok
}

const someInterface2: SomeInterface = {
  permissions: [Roles.Role1, Roles.Role1] // error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwEoQDbAM5wDeAUHJjsAIxwC8cA5FrpfQDSnm4BMtDTwXNsQC%20xYjACeYYHAAqyMLgCqiAJYREAHiUIQMJABMCeGFFWIA5q0y79iI3ACGiCQG0Aurw8A%20XiTKuAMpw5nBK7gBccACiIADG2MgGwNrWgb6gdg6IwABuwFBwAPxwrgB0FRhpnlHyisAq6lqxCUkpSmne1uWV1d4A3CKu4YNioJCwIYj6UABmjnEygRCowACS0wXzi0Qc0lCoqnh4TXi1CspqGpoA1sASELNwktKPnPgDImJxGiZweCt1ps5gtgFFlqsNjNtjI6P44PtDsdTlFXPw8GV%20JRrOjMRQuJ4APSEuAQG5fYg-RB-AGQ4EwrjgwFQragvx7ApIk6-VG4rE4igYrFEkkFKDQERAA)

Please be aware that it will heat your PCU if there will be a lot of keys in your enum or fails if it hits recursion limit. `TupleUnion` creates a union of all possible permutations of the tuple.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676439/create-constant-array-type-from-an-object-type/69676731#69676731) you can find an explanation how this works