# Type safe iteration over type properties

Tags: typescript

I need to have an iterator over `SomeType` type properties. `Object(instance)` is not OK cause it returns `string[]` not `Array<keyof SomeType>`. The following function solves the problem

```
export function keysof<T>(obj: Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>): Array<keyof T> {
    return Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;
}
```

The thing I really dislike here is that `obj` argument seem to be redundant, cause type should be enough to get it's properties. I'd like to be able to do something like the following

```
export function keysof<T>(): Array<keyof T> {
    return Object.keys(T) as Array<keyof T>;
}
```

But obviously that will throw `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` compilation error.

Is it possible to avoid passing `SomeType` instance to function?

Comment: In order to call `Object.keys` you should have an object. Hence, you `have` to pass this object as an argument to `keysof` function. Generic type `T` is erased after compilation. It means that you are trying to do this: `Object.keys()`. What do you expect from this?

Comment: `seem to be redundant` - it is not true. `obj` argument is `required`

Comment: @captain-yossarian good point. When I say redundant I mean that we're using only type of `obj`, and hence we're actually passing type for two times. But, yes, you're right, `T` exists only before ts compilation, so looks like it's impossible to remove this "redundancy"

Comment: What does "we're actually passing type for two times" mean?  Where are the two times?  Do you mean that `declare function f<T>(x: T): void;` mentions `T` twice?  If so, then note that `x => x * 3` mentions `x` twice but you wouldn't call it "redundant" and certainly couldn't replace it with `x => * 3`.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @jcalz good morning :D

Comment: @captain-yossarian please add your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call `Object.keys` you should have an object.

Hence, you have to pass this object as an argument to `keysof` function, like this:

```js
const keysof=<T,>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;
```

Generic type T is erased after compilation.

It means that if you want to remove `obj` argument and leave only `T`, like this:

```js
const keysof = <T,>() => Object.keys() as Array<keyof T>;
```

you will end up with this:

```js
const keysof = () => Object.keys();
```

Hence, you can get rid only explicit return type, like this:

```js
export function keysof<T>(obj:T) {
    return Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;
}
```

I think you should be aware of `Array<keyof T>` drawback. Because it allows you to use duplicates in your array. Consider this exmaple:

```js
const obj = { age: 42, name: 'John' }

const keys: Array<keyof typeof obj> = ['age', 'age', 'age'] // no compilation error
```

Is this what you want ? I don't think so. Because `Object.keys` can't produce duplicates in the result array.

There is another one approach. It also has own drawbacks :)

```js
// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];


const obj = { age: 42, name: 'John' }

const keys: TupleUnion<keyof typeof obj> = ['age', 'age', 'age'] // error
```

Above code causes a compilation error, just as you expect. **But** you can also boil some water on your PC/laptop since it CPU resurse consuming approach. Also it has own recursion limitations.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676439/create-constant-array-type-from-an-object-type/69676731#69676731) you can find step by step explanation of `TupleUnion` type utility

TL;TR

`TupleUnion` - produces a permutation of all possible `Object.keys` results