# Exhaustive list of keys of type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have some type `Foo` and I would like to extract the keys of `Foo`. For now I can do it manually like so.

```
type Foo = {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
};

const fooKeys = ["a", "b"] as Readonly<Array<keyof Foo>>;
```

But then somebody could come along and add `c` and fooKeys is still valid despite it not containing all the keys. How can I enforce that fooKeys must be exhaustive?

```
type Foo = {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c: string;
  };

const fooKeys = ["a", "b"] as Readonly<Array<keyof Foo>>;
```

My current workaround is to [define an example and infer everything](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAxEIYC8MA3gFAwxIBcMA5IqpnLZRDNAE4CWYA5jAB8YAVzAATOADMecMQBpyMAEY16ydFhZI2nHvyGiJ0sLIUVgq3Xy06o3PqQC+pUlACeaODFz4i7zyCS8OpMPqSgkLCSeADScG5sRADySgBWcMBQAHQA1vEQABQMGjh4AJSsMABKcEhi4BhuADwAghwcSM15boHeeAB8-QDcQA) from that, which is okay even though the types don't line up perfectly:

```
const exampleFoo = {
  a: 'example' as string | undefined,
  b: 'example' as string | undefined,
  c: 'example' as string
}

type Foo = typeof exampleFoo
const fooKeys = Object.keys(exampleFoo) as Readonly<Array<keyof Foo>>;
```

Maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: You can make a combination of all allowed states. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676439/create-constant-array-type-from-an-object-type/69676731#69676731) answer

Answer (score 4):

I think using an example object is ok.

This would be another option:

```
type Foo = {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c: string;
};

const Fields: Record<keyof Foo, 1> = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
const fooKeys = Object.keys(Fields) as Readonly<Array<keyof Foo>>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGB+ALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbk2wCNCTzr7GsBjI0y2gwC+DdNzhVSsChAA2AE2JEAShHFl5AHgDWEEHABmsBABooARgB8yNLiLmzTe2d4WhYiVIMIA0nuI2APJMAFZqwAB0uiDEABQwMgrEAJS4Aao48hKyIJoAgmRkOLnRhsZwlpZ0QA)

There are solutions to convert `keyof Foo` to a tuple type, but they tend to be unreliable as order in a union is not guaranteed to always be the same or if you generate a union with all possible combinations that will kill compiler performance.

You could also use a function to validate all keys have been specified:

```
type HasAllUnique<Tuple, Union, Seen = never> = 
  Tuple extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] 
    ? Head extends Seen 
      ? { " ERROR ": ["The following key appears more than once in the tuple:", Head]}
      : HasAllUnique<Tail, Exclude<Union, Head>, Head | Seen>
    : [Union] extends [never]? unknown : { " ERROR ": ["Some keys are missing from the tuple:", Union]}


function allKeys<T>() {
  return function<K extends Array<keyof T>>(...k : K & HasAllUnique<K, keyof T>) {
    return k
  }
}

allKeys<Foo>()("a") // errro
allKeys<Foo>()("a", "b") // error
allKeys<Foo>()("a", "b", "c") // ok
allKeys<Foo>()("a", "b", "c", "a") // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-uNGDqZotDmWjHe73QGvk2u52ngcANhv1TRwTWNAHpa6U3aL81qdSWEOXK9XTE0mDWoPXG6KyC3C23S52q49mn2e9x+4O4NmC0XdROjV3p72t-Oe9W6w33MP0EA)

[Playground Link with comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGB+ALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbk2wCNCTzr7GsBjI0y2gwC+DdKEhQAEjmIBBADbyAqlQoBHAK4QAPABUNYeRAA0UFRThVTAZQgQqyKFQgA3CGQB8yRgHofUABFEAHdoUgpFKAALHDcoCCMAW3tgYihqKGAo6GADIyg8KEZ9Q2gIAA9gewATNIBtagAzdykIHGrTADpuppbdHAiAXSLsKD8pWOhQkjsHSTbqqCYIRrgyaDwuAtb2+MqatNt7EdGx-wBJRpJEddyyBxwHdzI1qGCKLMzsqDhG5qpqhx4kkUlssIVUFAAESAXg3AIt7UAAogAlZEAeWRUHhUKIdShum+q0UcHetCgAGsICBcGBIDgyGlEmscjEHJZuNAMlkcnkIAQoaZ5u1BkIwWcoJcnHBgKYKtx5BpqizoNwNGR1lRgMCIMlNVBGi9Eukqok0lkcFqYnFgIgcLS2mRTI9Fu1Fh9MogPvYzTFLZMlrMZvYnQCoOtVQyIGKiNI5IpzJodP0IqZEeV5YqdOZLIKFh5c7sAD5QI5UDxbcYAdWgVug6xw3Gyi258VDv0yECimV5pgrFzS2aeiTAoEKW1xg+GFSqAPqzjcZEGYvGksH6TSOpH1JwkQoaUa1DrEDuDg0VHJVBJDmCUQojaggOIcHkbjSGS9ke4wAsVGIYsKZ4Xley4XFca57lKWqbqApjrGAaxao88Tqq87yfC2iR7sQQIJDqKR-qcUBEJCsIIii6KYtiuJQtYcDJBSVJpPS0CYcQ2FkgadFfDypT8qYk6iug6CNGeX4-rgigANKMXoHgABQAJRoIwtxqg4IlUGJljaJJewzrUUCyOqOAgNolIgO2ugePJ3SdOSRFQLpABkExxsoqiJjppjmZZHhKRgoyqfcFKMKKgk7vI0kgMQ2jwHA8kKXJUI4FCSnjM8LzoBFUUxXFCVJSlphQkwqXis8axZVJMl5YpBUCtCJVFdwpXjHA5KVZF1UIPlyX1cVfXNUVKVpf45VkOgQA)

You could also have a functionless approach if you are ok with defining an extra type after the constant:

```
const bad2= ["a", "b"] as const
type E2 = Validate<HasAllUnique<typeof bad2, keyof Foo>>

const ok = ["a", "b", "c"] as const
type E3 = Validate<HasAllUnique<typeof ok, keyof Foo>>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGB+ALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbk2wCNCTzr7GsBjI0y2gwC+DdKEhQAajgA2FACY5gEADwAVKBAAeyqvOJRyAVwgA+ZFDUNx0ABI5iAQRkyAqlQoBHE+qNgZEAA0UO4UcFTBAMoQEFQWVBAAbhBk5iiMan4Bmjqx+lBkEDjy4TIgUADa1ABmKVC2RfLBAHStNXVqOBQyALpQXFB49Y05uvnRsf3Y2EOoUABEAKIASssA8svzRBXzagAW0NVwLnAA7hxQANYQ5ThgkDhkBgC2cIWGezhx4dzQ1B-QYBZCAEebBBrFHpCAZYIj2JwuULeVSdbrBRZabgyIzyVShcLgxqmQnFKAAHygEyopgG23xVD62jGBgqCWSZB6Q2M0CIcyWqw2W0q80icGe0GuIAMj2gzwoxGIF2qZDFAMMwNBwXpUPQuu44VIUCYxQAjCgdjh5n0HFB9VRSGJwNBFiaLNI5IplCp4c43B5kSobHBqkbTcFJcHYAhTDT0HbDcb5AAmc3zS3BeZMK24Azx4COiSLJNu2QKJSqH2I-0+IMhxNJ8M3SPwOAxvUG4BQOCXCwWsELLMZ7jZm15gvOgDMJY95e9Dl9SJrTsj3cbIGb0djedD8inqfTA-782HGct1tzHfHUEWABZp2WvZW-V4l5BI4mJ2uN62aUA)

Comment: Very cool use of custom error type message not seen that before!

Comment: Couldn't you use that HasAllUnique as a generic somehow to validate the array has all the fields? Do you need the function? Something like `const fooKeys: HasAllUnique<Foo> = ['a', 'b', 'c' ] as const`

Comment: also if I could convert the suggestion to this format `const fooKeys = ensureAllKeys<Foo>(['a', 'b'] as const)`. I would accept this answer!

Comment: The function is needed. We need the actual type of `fooKeys` to validate them. We can use `as const` and validate with another type after

Comment: The lack of partial inference on function in TS means we can't specify just some of the types. You can add a parameter of type `T` to the inner function and pass in `null! as Foo`  `function allKeys<T, K extends Array<keyof T>>(o: T, ...k : K & HasAllUnique<K, keyof T>) {
  return k
}` and usage: `allKeys(null! as Foo, "a")`