# How to create a type of array values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a type that only accepts a specific combination of array values regardless of their order.

For example:

```
const acceptedCombo = ['a', 'b'];

function foo(param: MyType) {}

// Possible combos:
['a', 'b'] // OK
['b', 'a'] // OK
['a', 'b', 'c'] // TypeError - "c" is extra
['a'] // TypeError - "b" is missing
```

How can I define `MyType`?

Comment: So only those two combinations are valid?

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgAXBm)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676439/create-constant-array-type-from-an-object-type/69676731#69676731) answer is related, however it also allows less elements

Comment: There is also this: https://tsplay.dev/WYRv2w. It checks if all elements are present, although doubled elements are allowed. Has the advantage of not being combinatory explosive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```js
type MyType = [string, string];
```

Comment: this doesn't restrict the string to being 'a' and 'b' it could literally be anything.  
captain-yossarian from Ukraine answer in the comments should be sufficient.