# How to narrow a union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How could one narrow/split/decompose a possibly discriminated union type?

For example in the following I'd like to get the type with the `kind: "bar"` from `MyUnion`.

```js
type MyUnion = { kind: "foo", foo: number } | { kind: "bar", bar: string };

// Here I want to somehow get the type { kind: "bar", bar: string } from MyUnion
type Narrowed = NarrowUnion<MyUnion, { kind: "bar" }>;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have some use case not mentioned in the question, you can just use the provided [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
type Narrowed = Extract<MyUnion, { kind: "bar" }>;
/* type Narrowed = { kind: "bar"; bar: string;}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFA3lA1sogCYBcUARAGaqoUA0UNq5iArgLYBGEATlAF8oAH1wEiZSlwCGvBlBm9yAZ2C8iAc0EBuAFC6A9AagAJPtACSUAO7TEwKMFRRlqDhAAWqa1A0QHwB7QoJBihCTkFIryiipqmoJMvG6wCCjouiHQAHKyydYQxFhQAKIAHmrSAMbAADxwSGiIjHjhklGyFIIAfHoGAFSO4Dl53oXFrRKR0doKsnHqiBraAkA)

Answer (score 0):

If one needs to extract only a single "branch", then one could use:

```js
type NarrowUnion<Union, Match> =
    ExtractOne<Union> extends Match ? ExtractOne<Union> :
    SpliceOne<Union> extends never ? never :
    NarrowUnion<SpliceOne<Union>, Match>

type SpliceOne<Union> = Exclude<Union, ExtractOne<Union>>
type ExtractOne<Union> = ExtractParm<UnionToSect<UnionToParm<Union>>>

type UnionToParm<U> = U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never
type UnionToSect<U> = UnionToParm<U> extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never
type ExtractParm<F> = F extends { (a: infer A): void } ? A : never
```

Here `NarrowUnion` will narrow the union to the last "branch" of `Union` that extends `Match`.

*Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061272/107152).*

Comment: This is significantly more complicated than necessary to answer your question as asked.

Comment: @jcalz thanks! I thought this should be easier :-P